# Barking Up a Different Kind of Tree

Tags: evolution, fauna, domestication

(For this question, we are focusing on Old World canines, so *Canis latrans*, the coyote and the genus *Chyrsocyon* are excluded.)

Man's Best Friend has a polarly ironic ancestor--*Canis lupus*, the Grey Wolf.

[image]

Even today, the questions of where, how or when the select few wolves became the ancestors of all dogs (before *Vulpes vulpes* was added in the 1950s) are under constant debate.

But why?

What makes the Grey Wolf special as opposed to...

[image]

*Canis simensis* (Ethiopian Wolf)?

[image]

*Cuon alpinus*  (Dhole)?

[image]

*Lycaon pictus*  (African Wild Dog)?

Comment: I can't find resources on this right now so it's comments this time around, but I believe our ancestors hunted some pretty big and mean m.....f.....s back then. I don't see the smaller, more fragile varieties of wolves/wild dogs being much help against them.

Comment: I edited my answer. My research indicted that it wasn't just the grey wolf, but that they were all European.

Comment: [Reminder to close-voters](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3773/6986)... (This is getting annoying...)

Comment: @Frostfyre  Why would you want to close this?

Comment: I didn't vote to close it. I'm annoyed that I have to keep putting that link on questions because other users don't comment on why they're voting to close.

Comment: @Renan, I wonder how long it took to for humans to utilize dogs for small, quick game.  Think sighthounds and rabbits.

Comment: @Frostfyre I'm with you on that. And if this question gets closed I'll vote to reopen asap. This is a good question.

Comment: I VTC'd this question as not related to worldbuilding because I cannot pull *any* relation between this question and worldbuilding. How does knowing what makes the grey wolf "special" compared to another species of animal relate to worldbuilding at all? You're asking about why something happened in our current world. If anything, this is a question for some history/evolution hybrid site, not worldbuilding.

Comment: I'll also point out that the current 3 answers to this question are all very different yet at the same time completely valid, which to me, means that even if I didn't VTC this as off-topic I would've VTC'd it as opinion based. There is no way objective way here for you to select the "correct" or "best" answer.

Comment: *What makes the grey wolf special?* this question could be on topic and science based IF you specified what you mean and your clarification was scientifically based on biological attributes of the animal.

Comment: @James  Didn't you see the answers below?

Comment: @JohnWDailey The point is that is for YOU to define not the people answering.

Comment: @James  Then why did I ask in the first place?

Answer (score 6):

That's just how it shook out, methinks. Take a look at [this fantastic experiment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jFGNQScRNY).

The most awesome thing about it, is that these foxes began to show the variation in coloring that dogs do. It's called the [Russian Fox Experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Domesticated_Red_Fox). Google it if that link goes away. Basically, for about 25 years or so, Russians took wild foxes and selectively bred them for tameness. They now have a domesticated fox that in a lot of ways closely resembles a dog. That's in an evolutionary blink of an eye.

So why grey wolves? The answer is actually that it wasn't just grey wolves. There are blue wolves (Switzerland), grey wolves, and Ukrainian wolves. We do know that they are ALL European wolves. Well, there could have been enough that had the "tame" quality to make it easier for humans to develop them through breeding. These other types of wolves might have been less common and less predisposed to have enough tame genetics in order to get a viable population. Now, I do believe that it happened very quickly and that all of these likely have the capability.

I think that conditions were just right and that humans developed this breeding very quickly on an evolutionary scale, as was proven in the Russian Fox experiment. While the others may have been developed that way, those died out or reintegrated back into the wild population.

This video on the [pathway and timing should be of interest](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VaS-teo33Zo). If you watch you will see that dogs and wolves of ALL TYPES share a common ancestor. It is not a straight line from grey wolves. And admixture breeding makes things problematic.

Comment: A summary of the Fox experiment would be a good addition. YouTube videos have a habit of disappearing or not being available in your country.

Comment: For the time being, I added a link to the relevant Wikipedia article. Those have a little less tendency towards disappearing or suffering from selective availability.

Answer (score 2):

## Where Were Dogs Domesticated

According to [this article](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2016/06/04/dna-evidence-suggests-humans-may-have-domesticated-dogs-twice/), and [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin_of_the_domestic_dog#Two_domestication_events), which then goes on to talk about some papers in academic journals, claims there are two hypotheses about where dogs were first domesticated.

The first says dogs were domesticated in Europe around 15 000 years ago. Obviously, these humans didn't order a dog to domesticate from a faraway land; they used the wolves that were present in their range.

The second says there is some DNA evidence that there was no one place where dogs were domesticated- there may have been two! The other proposed place (based off of mitochondrial DNA) is somewhere in... Central Asia or China 12 500 years ago.

## So What Wolf Lived in those Areas?

The Grey Wolf Range (From Wikipedia):[image: Covers Those Areas]

The Ethiopian Wolf... seems to have only lived in [a small part of Africa](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/Canis_simensis_subspecies_range.png), far from the first dog tamers.

The African Wild Dog seems to be quite happy [not crossing the Sahara](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/92/African_Wild_Dog_Distrbution.jpg), and was therefore far from these dog tamers.

The Dhole, however, may have been eligible for domestication:
[image: Central Asia? China? Check.]

So our current best friends may have a little Dhole in them, but it seems the grey wolf was selected simply because it was at the right place at the right time.

## But Wait!

It seems that the dogs of today are not descendants of Canis Lupus! This other ancestor could be the [megafaunal wolf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megafaunal_wolf), which became a species around the same time that Canis Lupus did.
[image: NOT CANIS LUPUS!?]
Some think this megafaunal wolf hunted big game, whereas canis lupus was a little less adventurous. It may have been this choice of prey that incentivized humans and wolves to get close together, and eventually work together.

Answer (score 1):

The Ethiopian wolf (a.k.a. Simien Jackal) lives in packs but hunts alone. Also their prey are rodents and the like, not big game. Here's a [BBC wildlife video about them.](http://www.bbc.co.uk/nature/life/Ethiopian_Wolf#p00c27wx) So we'd only domesticate them if we wanted a dog-shaped 'cat' to catch rats for us!

Comment: There are dogs that specialize in this skill (ratting), so it's ironic that they are descended from large game hunting wolves rather than small game hunting dogs.

Comment: @wizardzz. Yeah, I suspect we invented the snare really early on to catch rat/gopher/rabbit sized prey, then invented ratters and domesticated ferrets much later when it was a 'destroying vermin' job rather than a 'what's for lunch' job.

Comment: I suspect that to be true, too.